# Arduino Void Loop

Tags: arduino, void

For class, I developed the following code. My teacher, on the other hand, wants me to condense it. If anyone has any recommendations, I would be grateful. Thanks.

```
    void setup()
{
  DDRD = 0b11111111;
  DDRB = 0b00000001;
}

void loop()
 
{
  PORTD = 0b00000001;
  PORTB = 0b00000000;
  delay(t);
  PORTD = 0b00000010;
  PORTB = 0b00000000;
  delay(t);
  PORTD = 0b00000100;
  PORTB = 0b00000000;
  delay(t);
  PORTD = 0b00001000;
  PORTB = 0b00000000;
  delay(t);
  PORTD = 0b00010000;
  PORTB = 0b00000000;
  delay(t);
  PORTD = 0b00100000;
  PORTB = 0b00000000;
  delay(t);
  PORTD = 0b01000000;
  PORTB = 0b00000000;
  delay(t);
  PORTD = 0b10000000;
  PORTB = 0b00000000;
  delay(;
  PORTD = 0b00000000;
  PORTB = 0b00000001;
  delay(t);
  
}
```

Comment: You could use a for-loop that sets PORTD to an uint8_t variable containing 1<<i (i goes from 0 to 7) and sets PORTB to 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should loop through the values you want to set PORTD to. It shifts the '1' bit once for every loop, and because bitval can only hold a byte (8 bits) the eighth shift will make bitval zero, ending the loop.

```
void loop()
{
    for (byte bitval = 1; bitval != 0; bitval <<= 1)
    {
        PORTD = bitval;
        PORTB = 0;
        delay(t);
    }
    PORTD = 0;
    PORTB = 1;
    delay(t);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very very much!! YOU ROCK!